# How to transfer user login session from app to uiwebview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, session, authentication, uiwebview

I'm trying to transfer the login session from app to uiwebview so that user doesn't want to login again in uiwebview. Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: what you want to add in web view initially ?

Comment: I have to add app login credentials in uiwebview. I'm doing an native app which is already in web application.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by

1) Setting the user parameters required, in `header of the request url` for login like userID, authkey, email.
like this

```
NSString * userAgent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@@@%@@@@",authKey];
[request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

2)While on the Web end you have to check for for above parameters & logged in at web Page.